# Why would ASP.NET not be able to find asp:UpdateProgress?

Tags: .net, asp.net, installation, upgrade, server-error

Basically I am upgrading from 1.1 to .NET 3.5 SP1 and replacing an old .NET 1.1 WebForms application with its newer .NET 3.5 version.

- I run the .net 3.5 sp1 installer ([dotnetfx35setup.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en))
- I run the crystal reports redistributable installer
- I set up a new application pool
- I set up a new website using the directory with the new files, using ASP.NET 2.0 and the new application pool

I have done this exact same process on 5 different (relatively) identical boxes and it worked on every single one except for the current one.

Here when I try to navigate to the home page I get an error: **Parser Error Message: unkown server tag asp:UpdateProgress**
You can see the full error here: http://pastebin.com/f460e58bd

Since UpdateProgress is in System.Web.Extensibility.dll I checked the GAC - it is not installed.  So I tried moving it manually into the applications bin directory - this didn't fix it.  I then tried copying gacutil to the machine and installing the file to the GAC manually, the install succeeded but my application still is failing and I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can try?

The server is a Windows 2003 Server SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the bottom of your web.confg:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

If it works then it's a problem with your pages looking for the specific older version of the System.Web.Extensions DLL.  A recompile of the DLLs that reference System.Web.Extensions should fix it also.

Also [here's the much more common error people see](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMB_en-USUS295US304&q=Parser+Error+Message:+unknown+server+tag+asp:ScriptManager&btnG=Search), and a better Google search to get you pointed in the right direction since the ScriptManager is usually the first System.Web.Extensions control parsed.

Comment: +1 million!  Your comment made me check my web.config.  For some reason my web config file got copied over as blank

Answer (score 1):

Is you Register directive on the page/control set correctly?  Does it set the TagPrefix attribute to "as"?

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice in the question it reference as:UpdateProgress instead of asp:UpdateProgress.